# Sum of a p-series with coefficients

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, harmonic-numbers, toeplitz-matrices

I am trying t find an expression for the partial sum of a p-like-series.  The problem comes from trying to sum the elements of a matrix whose entries are inversely related to their distance from the diagonal.

$$
\begin{matrix}
k^{-\alpha} & (k+1)^{-\alpha} & (k+2)^{-\alpha} & (k+3)^{-\alpha} & (k+4)^{-\alpha} & (k+5)^{-\alpha} & (k+6)^{-\alpha} & (k+7)^{-\alpha}\\
  & k^{-\alpha} & (k+1)^{-\alpha} & (k+2)^{-\alpha} & (k+3)^{-\alpha} & (k+4)^{-\alpha} & (k+5)^{-\alpha} & (k+6)^{-\alpha} \\
 & & k^{-\alpha} & (k+1)^{-\alpha} & (k+2)^{-\alpha} & (k+3)^{-\alpha} & (k+4)^{-\alpha} & (k+5)^{-\alpha} \\
& & & k^{-\alpha} & (k+1)^{-\alpha} & (k+2)^{-\alpha} & (k+3)^{-\alpha} & (k+4)^{-\alpha} & \\
& & & & k^{-\alpha} & (k+1)^{-\alpha} & (k+2)^{-\alpha} & (k+3)^{-\alpha} \\
& & & & & k^{-\alpha} & (k+1)^{-\alpha} & (k+2)^{-\alpha} \\
& & & & & & k^{-\alpha} & (k+1)^{-\alpha} \\
& & & & & & & k^{-\alpha}
\end{matrix}
$$

Now, if I divide this matrix into 2 $\times$ 2 squares and sum the elements, I get

$$
\tiny
\begin{matrix}
2k^{-\alpha} + (k+1)^{-\alpha} & (k+1)^{-\alpha} + 2(k+2)^{-\alpha} + (k+3)^{-\alpha} & (k+3)^{-\alpha} + 2(k+4)^{-\alpha} + (k+5)^{-\alpha} & (k+5)^{-\alpha} + 2(k+6)^{-\alpha} + (k+7)^{-\alpha} \\
& 2k^{-\alpha} + (k+1)^{-\alpha} & (k+1)^{-\alpha} + 2(k+2)^{-\alpha} + (k+3)^{-\alpha} & (k+3)^{-\alpha} + 2(k+4)^{-\alpha} + (k+5)^{-\alpha} \\
& & 2k^{-\alpha} + (k+1)^{-\alpha} & (k+1)^{-\alpha} + 2(k+2)^{-\alpha} + (k+3)^{-\alpha} \\
& & & 2k^{-\alpha} + (k+1)^{-\alpha}
\end{matrix}
\normalsize
$$

If I repeat the process one more time we get:

$$
\tiny
\begin{matrix}
4k^{-\alpha} + 3(k+1)^{-\alpha} + 2(k+2)^{-\alpha} + (k+3)^{-\alpha} & (k+1)^{-\alpha} + 2(k+2)^{-\alpha} + 3(k+3)^{-\alpha} + 4(k+4)^{-\alpha} + 3(k+5)^{-\alpha} + 2(k+6)^{-\alpha} + (k+7)^{-\alpha}  \\
 & 4k^{-\alpha} + 3(k+1)^{-\alpha} + 2(k+2)^{-\alpha} + (k+3)^{-\alpha}
\end{matrix}
\normalsize
$$

The pattern which emerges is some sort of weighted p-series with strictly deceasing coefficients on the diagonal, and coefficients that increase and decrease on the off diagonals, starting at 1, then increasing to $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$, then decreasing and returning to 1 again.

**MY QUESTIONS**:

- Is there a name for such a series?
- Is there an approximation for such a sum? (I found [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1576502/calculate-finite-p-series) about approximating p-series sums, but the addition of the above coefficients complicate the issue)

**Things to note**:
$k$ is likely to be set to $0$
$\alpha \gt 1$
The above process is likely to be repeated up to 18 times on a very large matrix, so approximations to a large sum are welcome.

---

**TO SUMMARISE**

- Let's set k = 0.
- We have a square matrix with dimension $\propto 2^J$.
- Let $r$ and $c$ represent the row and column, respectively.
- Each cell equals $(c - r)^{-\alpha} * I(r < c)$
- I have a square, upper triangular Toeplitz matrix

$$
\begin{matrix}
0 & 1^{-\alpha} & 2^{-\alpha} & 3^{-\alpha} & 4^{-\alpha} & 5^{-\alpha} & 6^{-\alpha} & 7^{-\alpha} & ...\\
  & 0 & 1^{-\alpha} & 2^{-\alpha} & 3^{-\alpha} & 4^{-\alpha} & 5^{-\alpha} & 6^{-\alpha} & ...\\
 & & 0 & 1^{-\alpha} & 2^{-\alpha} & 3^{-\alpha} & 4^{-\alpha} & 5^{-\alpha} & ... \\
& & & 0 & 1^{-\alpha} & 2^{-\alpha} & 3^{-\alpha} & 4^{-\alpha} & ...\\
& & & & 0 & 1^{-\alpha} & 2^{-\alpha} & 3^{-\alpha} & ...\\
& & & & & 0 & 1^{-\alpha} & 2^{-\alpha} & ...\\
& & & & & & 0 & 1^{-\alpha} & ...\\
& & & & & & & 0 & ... \\
& & & & & & & & \ddots
\end{matrix}
$$

- I break the matrix into square bins of size $2^j$, $j \in {1,2,3,...., J}$
- The number of diagonals within each square bin (and therefore the number of unique terms) is 2 x dimension - 1 = $2^{j+1} - 1$.
- Since the coefficients start at 1, ascend to the midpoint, and then descend back to 1, the middle (and therefore maximum) coefficient is $\frac{(2^{j+1} - 1)+1}{2} = 2^j$.
- The summands within each square bin change as they move further away from the diagonal.  If we consider the $b^{th}$ bin from the diagonal, $b \in {1,2,3,..., 2^{J-j}}$ then the maximum summand is $(b2^j - 1)$
- The minimum summand is the maximum summand - # of diagonal elements + 1 = $(b2^j - 1) - (2^{j+1} - 1) + 1 = b2^j - 2^{j+1} + 1$
- Therefore, the midpoint summand will be $\frac{max + min}{2} = \frac{(b2^j - 1)+(b2^j - 2^{j+1} + 1)}{2} = \frac{b2^{j+1} - 2^{j+1}}{2} = (b-1)*2^j$
- Bringing this all together, we get:  (diagonal term) + (lower triangle terms) + (Upper triangle terms).

$$2^j((b-1)2^j)^{-\alpha} + \sum_{i=1}^{2^j - 1}(2^j -i)((b-1)2^j - i)^{-\alpha} + \sum_{i=1}^{2^j - 1}(2^j -i)((b-1)2^j + i)^{-\alpha}$$

Note that if we are on one of the "triangular" diagonal bins, the first two terms evaluate to ZERO, since $r \ge c$

$$= 2^j((b-1)2^j)^{-\alpha} + \sum_{i=1}^{2^j - 1}(2^j -i)((b-1)2^j - i)^{-\alpha} + \sum_{i=1}^{2^j - 1}(2^j -i)((b-1)2^j + i)^{-\alpha}$$

In order to make the above expression conform with Dr. Wolfgang Hintze's solution below, I simply need to change the index.

$\ell = (2^j - i) \rightarrow (i = 2^j - k)$

$$
\begin{align}
& 2^j((b-1)2^j)^{-\alpha} + \sum_{i=1}^{2^j - 1}(2^j -i)((b-1)2^j - i)^{-\alpha} + \sum_{i=1}^{2^j - 1}(2^j -i)((b-1)2^j + i)^{-\alpha} \\
& = 2^j((b-1)2^j)^{-\alpha} + \sum_{\ell=1}^{2^j - 1}\ell((b-1)2^j - (2^j - \ell))^{-\alpha} + \sum_{\ell=1}^{2^j - 1}\ell((b-1)2^j + (2^j - \ell))^{-\alpha} \\
& = 2^j((b-1)2^j)^{-\alpha} + \sum_{\ell=1}^{2^j - 1}\ell((b-2)2^j + \ell)^{-\alpha} + \sum_{\ell=1}^{2^j - 1}\ell(b2^j - \ell)^{-\alpha} \\
& = 2^j((b-1)2^j)^{-\alpha} + \sum_{\ell=1}^{2^j - 1}\ell(\ell + (b-2)2^j)^{-\alpha} + \sum_{\ell=1}^{2^j - 1}\ell(- \ell + b2^j)^{-\alpha} \\
\end{align}
$$

As a final pass, I also came up with the following expression by not changing the term in the final sum, instead simply distributing the power summand across the coefficient term:

$$
\begin{align}
2^j((b-1)2^j)^{-\alpha} &+ \sum_{\ell=1}^{2^j - 1}\ell(\ell + (b-2)2^j)^{-\alpha} \\
& + 2^j\sum_{i=1}^{2^j - 1}(i + (b-1)2^j)^{-\alpha} \\
& - \sum_{i=1}^{2^j - 1}i(i + (b-1)2^j)^{-\alpha}
\end{align}
$$

$$
\begin{align}
2^j((b-1)2^j)^{-\alpha} &+ s\left((b-2)2^j, \alpha, 1, 2^j - 1\right) \\
& + 2^j\left\{\zeta(\alpha, (b-1)2^j +1) - \zeta(\alpha, (b-2)2^j -1)\right\} \\
& - s\left((b-1)2^j, \alpha, 1, 2^j - 1\right)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I would find it useful if you give a name to your expressions of interest. And please avoid the use of square brackets ( [ and ] ) which are reserved for specific purposes.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I understand your problem correctly but it seems that you are interested in sums of the type

$$s(k,\alpha,m,n)=\sum _{i=0}^n i^m (i+k)^{-\alpha }\tag{1}$$

For $m=0$ we have

$$s(k,\alpha,0,n)=\zeta (-a,k)-\zeta (-a,k+n+1)\tag{2}$$

where $\zeta (r,n)$ is the Hurwitz Zeta function.

For general integer $m$ it is useful to start from the genrating function

$$\begin{align}g(z)= & \sum _{i=0}^n z^i (i+k)^{-\alpha }\\=& \Phi (z,\alpha ,k)-z^{n+1} \Phi (z,\alpha ,k+n+1)
\end{align}\tag{3}$$

where $\Phi (z,\alpha ,k)$ is the Lerch $\Phi$ function.

You can generate the $m$-th power of $i$ by applying the operation $(z \frac{\partial}{\partial z})^m$ to $g(z)$ and letting $z\to 1$.

Since the derivative

$$z \frac{\partial \Phi (z,\alpha ,k)}{\partial z} = \Phi (z,\alpha -1,k)-k \Phi (z,\alpha ,k)\tag{4}$$

can also be expressed in terms of the Lerch $\Phi$-funcition we conclude that, the sum $(1)$ can be expressed in terms of the Lerch function $\Phi (z,\alpha ,k)$.

Comment: Also, is there a name for the sums of type (,,,)??

Comment: Thank you, Dr. Hintze! I've added to my question by deriving the summation more explicitly, and tried my best to write the final expression as as close to your solution as possible. Would you mind taking a look and letting me know what you think? In my case, the exponent m=1.

Comment: @ Lewkrr It looks good, and see my comment to your OP. If you find my answer useful you might consider upvoting it.